# Replace text within a table for all cells that contain a given word for n columns

Tags: excel, replace, powerbi, powerquery

I have data within a table that occasionally has been inputted with text to say something like not available or No Data etc. I wish to replace each instance a cell contains `no` that this is then replaced with null across n number of columns. I don't know every type of word that has been entered but it looks as though each cell to be converted to null contains `no` as characters so I will go with this.

i.e.

[image]

Is there any way to combine `if text.contains([n columns],"no") then null else [n columns]

Comment: Is it "No" in any column zero's out all the column?

Comment: Sorry could to rephrase that? Basically any cell that contains ‘no’ is converted to null. The remaining values in the columns/table are left unchanged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In powerquery, this removes the content of any cell containing (No,NO,no,nO) and converts to a null

Click select the first column, right click, Unpivot other columns

click select Value column and transform ... data type .. text

right click Value column and transform  ... lower case

we really don't want that so change this in the formula bar

```
= Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type1",{{"Value", Text.Lower, type text}})
```

to resemble this instead  (which also ignore the Case of the No)

```
= Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type1",{{"Value", each if Text.Contains(_,"no", Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) then null else _, type text}})
```

click select attribute column

Transform ... pivot column

values column:Value, Advanced ... don’t aggregate

sample full code:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Column"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{{"Value", type text}}),
#"CheckForNo" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type1",{{"Value", each if Text.Contains(_,"no", Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) then null else _, type text}}),
#"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"CheckForNo", List.Distinct(#"Lowercased Text"[Attribute]), "Attribute", "Value")
in  #"Pivoted Column"
```